# Unit testing a controller that uses moment js

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, momentjs

I am looking to write a unit test for a controller that uses moment.js throughout the controller, like in the code snippet below. Im curious if there is a best practice for this. Since its a third party library do I just sub out the values for hard coded ones or should I be testing moment.js itself as well?

```
$scope.analytics = {
      loading: false,
      dateRange: {
         start: moment().subtract(30, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
         end: moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      }
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't test external library. 
You don't know the codebase, it would take ages, you'r using it because it make you gain some times, if you loose it testing it... there is no point.

I would try to use only libraries that have some tests. Or mostly.

And for the case of momentjs specificaly they have test, so what you should test is you'r integration of that lib, using mock.